# C# How to convert ASCII Ledger-CLI output to UTF-8 input for further processing

Tags: python, c#, .net-core, utf-8, character-encoding

I have to create a C# core command-line app to replace and extend a working python script.

Basically, the first step is to capture the output of the Ledger command-line accounting program and process it further on. I believe that the output is ASCII: the `€` is displayed as `Γé¼`.

The python script converts the output to UTF-8 with a simple `output.decode("utf-8")` which turns all `Γé¼` nicely into `€`

My C# program captures the output in a variable and I have been searching around the net for a simple recipe to convert it to UTF-8 (i.e. achieve the python functionality) in Dotnet core, but I haven't found a working one yet.

This is how I capture the output:

```
public string Fetch(string naam)
{
    using (Process p = new Process())
    {
         p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\ledger.exe";
         p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-f c:\\Users\\guivho\\ledger\\boekhouding.ledger -U csv t:{naam} --sort date";
         p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
         p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
         p.Start();
         string ouput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
         p.WaitForExit();
         return ouput;
    }
}
```

Please advise and TIA for any help or suggestions.

Comment: _I believe that the output is ascii_ Forget the word "ascii"... it doesn't mean what you think. ascii is only 128 characters 0-127. There is nothing ascii in what you are writing.

Comment: And for utf8 there is an aptly named `Encoding.UTF8` object. But given that it is unclear how you "capture the output", nothing more can be said about how to do everything.

Comment: I have added the function that runs Ledger and fetches its output. I just need to convert this output so that `€` displays as `€`, and not as `Γé¼`. Note that there may be other multi-byte characters in the output, it's just that the `€` iso obviously omnipresent in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the output of the ledger program.
Solved the issue by having `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` as the first instruction of the Main function of the program before it ever called Ledger (which was completely unrelated to the problem):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        ...
    }
```

Thanks for all help, and a Happy Healthy New Year to you all!